# How to get rid of file reference in doxygen config file?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a bunch of file references when i run doxygen on my c code and I'd rather it not say where on my machine the file is located. how do i get rid of this in the config file? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Doxyfile, set

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to show part of the path, then use

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH = /part/of/the/path/to/strip
```